# Protractor - ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible error on previous disabled button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have a table, with rows and I want to edit the first row.
For this, I have an edit button witch is disabled (ng-disabled) until I select a row. I have a complex directive for this button and also a property called "disabled" on the object. After I select the row I get the error:

`ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible`

Also, I have an Add button, which is always active and can be selected.

The HTML code for Add and Edit button is:

```
<div class="tbl" >
<div class="table"heading" >
<div style="float: right;" >
<div  ng- show="canBeResized &amp;&amp; !isExpandedTable &amp;&amp; !isMobile" class="extend"
ng - click="expand()" tabindex= "0" role= "button"  > <i class="fa fa-expand" > </i></div>
</div>
< div class="table" style= "float:right;" >
<div style="text-align: center !important;" ng- show="!(!actions || actions.length == 0)" class="ng-scope" >
<div class="skiplink" > <a href="#content" > skip navigation links< /a></div >
<ul id="action" class="table" >
<li ng- repeat="act in actions" id= "btn" class="ng-scope" >
<a ng-if="(act.command || act.commandList) &amp;&amp; (act.name != 'CheckAll' &amp;&amp; act.code != 'checkAll')" href= ""
ng - click="invokeAction(act.code || act.name, null, act.disabled, act.hasMultiSelect)" ng- disabled="isDisabledAction(act.code || act.name, act.disabled, act.hasMultiSelect)"
class="ng-scope" >
<i ng-if="act.command &amp;&amp; (act.name == 'Add' || act.code == 'add')" class="fa fa-plus ng-scope" > </i>
< span class="hidden" > Add < /span></a >
</li>
< li ng- repeat="act in actions" id= "btn" class="ng-scope" >
<a ng-if="(act.command || act.commandList) &amp;&amp; (act.name != 'CheckAll' &amp;&amp; act.code != 'checkAll')" href= ""
ng - click="invokeAction(act.code || act.name, null, act.disabled, act.hasMultiSelect)" ng- disabled="isDisabledAction(act.code || act.name, act.disabled, act.hasMultiSelect)"
class="ng-scope" disabled= "disabled" >
<i ng-if="act.command &amp;&amp; (act.name == 'Edit' || act.code == 'edit')" class="fa fa-pencil ng-scope" > </i>
< span class="hidden" > Edit < /span></a >
</li>
< /ul>
< /div>
< /div>
< div class="table" > <span class="caption"> </span><span class="tbl"></span>
<div class="btn" ng- show="" >
<button type="button" id= "btnLeft" ng- disabled="_isDisabledNextButton" aria- label="Next" class="btn btn-radius"
ng - click="prevPage()" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" > </i></button>
<!--ngRepeat: p in Pages-- >
<button type="button" id= "btnRight" ng- disabled="_isDisabledPrevButton" aria- label="Previous" class="btn btn-radius"
ng - click="nextPage()" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" > </i></button>
</div>
< /div>
< /div>
< /div>
```

I've tried this to select the row I want to Edit:

```
var row = element(by.xpath('//[@id="List"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/span'));
row.click();
```

and after to select Edit button like this:

```
 var editButton = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="btnedit"]/a'));
    editButton.click();
```

but it doesnt'work even to select the row ....

Comment: Can you add your html code in the question, so that your question has every other detail that needs to be answered for? Thanks

Comment: Done, I've edited the post. :)

Comment: If you've got an id on the element, use by.id, which is more precise, instead of by.xpath, which is only going to find what you tell it to find, whether that is what you want or not.

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code for the table as well? Also please include the block of test code which fails and a clear indication of exactly which line generates the "element not visible" error? Thanks.

Comment: I can't post the HTML code for the table, I'm not allowed from work.